# Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security (Empty Frame URL)

Tags: nginx, content-security-policy

I have a **Jira** instance running under **nginx** and we have some **CSPs** configured in **nginx**.

Now we are installing an app that generates links that trigger a browser extension, the **URLs** start with **goedit**:

The vendor of the app suggests this **CSP** header:

`add_header` Content-Security-Policy

```
default-src https: goedit: wss: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
img-src https: data: 'unsafe-inline'" always;
```

I am now trying to incorporate this into our CSP header.
Our CSP Header includes

```
frame-src '' https://assets.zendesk.com https://www.facebook.com https://$server_name;
```

When I now click on one of the Links for that app I get this error message in the console:

Refused to frame `''` because it violates the following **Content Security Policy**

```
directive: "frame-src https://assets.zendesk.com https://www.facebook.com https://my-server.dein-james.de".
```

I am wondering: What do I need to put into the frame-src to allow this kind of link ('')?

I'd rather not drop the whole frame-src part, I want to keep those whitelisted.

thanks in advance
Jens

Answer (score 3):

I know this is quite an old thread now but I came across a similar issue today. With mine I was using data: in the object-src and I had to ensure data: was then in the frame-src.

Therefore I would check that in frame-src you include any schema's, I suspect it might be the goedit: or wss: in your example?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize "data:" is regarded as a source/protocol.

Answer (score 2):

Though this is old, I found that:

1. Stefan's solution works.
2. I had a situation where dynamic iframes (meaning, an iframe added dynamically) were attempting to load a pdf for nice display (in chrome), and though the scp contained "self" for frame-src, and the pdf was from the current domain, some users couldn't see the content, their consoles showed the above error. After messing around, found that simply there is a setting to tweak in the chrome browser - go into the settings, search "pdf" and find the section where you can toggle for pdf the setting that makes pdf's download automatically, vs display in the browser.

Comment: p.s. the reason that Stefan's solution works is that with the above settings, chrome converts the iframe object into it's own data object, which is an implementation of a "download" button for that current pdf.
so adding "data:" to the csp policy, allows that data object to load. but then of course, you will see a download button and not the document.

This is all speaking for a case of a pdf with the above error. hope this helps or applies for other types of files too.